# Jmeter>> Exact N Request per user >> Which thread group to use when we want to control/send the exact number of requests

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

My Organization is having set of 5 http requests. R1,R2 to R5. Each http request uses Addr and City as input along with user ids. And there are 500 Users in csv sheet to use for those 5 requests. We'd like to have aprrox or exact 50 request per user, divided into 5 api requests. And additional condition is R1 should have more weight in 50 req
So it looks like this

```
User1 >> R1=20Request, R2=10Request, R3=10Request, R4=5Request, R5=5Request >> 50
User2 >> R1=20Request, R2=10Request, R3=10Request, R4=5Request, R5=5Request >> 50
User3 >> R1=20Request, R2=10Request, R3=10Request, R4=5Request, R5=5Request >> 50
..
User500 >> R1=20Request, R2=10Request, R3=10Request, R4=5Request, R5=5Request >> 50
```

I have tried following test plans

```
Test plan 1 (10 Thread, loop count 5, loop controller loop count 1)
>>CSV Data Config Users
>>CSV Data Config Addr
>>CSV Data Config City
>>Thread Group 
 >> loop controller
  >> R1
  >> R2
  >> R3
  >> R4
  >> R5
```

```
Test plan 2 ( Using % distribution for Throughput controller with 5min run)
>>CSV Data Config Users
>>CSV Data Config Addr
>>CSV Data Config City
>>Ultimate Thread Group 
 >> Throughtput controller
  >> R1
>> Throughtput controller
  >> R2
>> Throughtput controller
  >> R3
>> Throughtput controller
  >> R4
>> Throughtput controller
  >> R5
```

```
Test plan 3 (10 Thread, loop count 5, loop controller loop count 1)
>>CSV Data Config Usrs
>>setUp Thread Group
>>CSV Data Config Addr
>>CSV Data Config City 
 >> loop controller
  >> R1
  >> R2
  >> R3
  >> R4
  >> R5
```

```
Test plan 4 (10 Thread, loop count 5, loop controller 1 loop count 1, LC2 count 2)
>>CSV Data Config Users
>>CSV Data Config Addr
>>CSV Data Config City
>>Thread Group 
 >> loop controller 1
  >> R2
  >> R3
  >> R4
  >> R5
>> loop controller 2
  >> R1
```

Problem statement:

1. In TestPlan1,3 & 4 we are able to use all of the users from CSV but request count is not getting to 50 at all
2. In TestPlan2 all users from csv are not getting used and request count sometime exceeds and sometime seen below 50

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is just to add another copy of the `R1` like:

```
Test plan 1 (10 Thread, loop count 5, loop controller loop count 1)
>>CSV Data Config Users
>>CSV Data Config Addr
>>CSV Data Config City
>>Thread Group 
 >> loop controller
  >> R1
  >> R1 (another copy)
  >> R2
  >> R3
  >> R4
  >> R5
```

instead of "stupid" copying and pasting a HTTP Request sampler you can define a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) containing this `R1` request and reference it twice using [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)

If your "weight" criteria are more complex it might be a better idea to consider using [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide/) instead.